# Magento 2.2.6 | Unable to upgrade

Tags: magento2, php, upgrade

Since Magento 2.2.6 was released not long ago we wanted to update our installation via CLI. Unfortunatly i stepped accross a few problems.

**Steps I've done so far**

`composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update`

`composer update`

And thats where the problems kick in, after loading the repos for a while i get the following error:

`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for doctrine/annotations 1.6.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.6.0].`

I thought it will be an easy fix by just using the php71 prefix but it seems like Magento dont want that since i get this line then

`- magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.`

How do i update if the php requirements are that different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message you system still taking your old php version
your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.

Before running this command,

> `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update`

```
Please do below  step:
```

- Stop all Magento CRON, means remove all  Magento cron from server
  cron list.
- Remove `.setup_cronjob_status,.update_cronjob_status,composer.json`
  form var folder.
- Remove/Flush all magento cache.

Comment: Whoups, typo. I copied the command from the official docs. I've used 2.2.6.

Comment: what about `- magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.22) does not satisfy that requirement.Please  update the post accordingly your error

`

Comment: There was the misstake. Seems like ive required `2.1.6` instead of `2.2.6`... Question can be closed

Answer (score 3):

Please upgrade it using composer like that

Edit **composer.json**  in root file from

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.5",
```

To below line

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.6",
```

And after this run command

```
composer update
```

After this run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: This entry isn't found in the composer.json file