# Upgrade from magento 2.2.5 to 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, version

I got this error when tring to run this command :

```
composer update magento/product-community-edition:2.2.6 --with-dependencies
```

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   Invalid credentials for
>   'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-store/magento-module-store-100.2.4.0.zip',
>   aborting.

```
{    "http-basic": {
       "repo.magento.com": {
          "username": "09ec672d88a59a13106aa5f0c0bf9c76",
          "password": "406bd6f5f7e785ae1e61b779e2a4e3a3"
       } 
 }
}
```

So can i ask alternative solution download the latest version and just replace vendor ?

Comment: Are the credentials on auth.json the same as the access key of your magento user https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html ?

Comment: yes they are the same

Comment: Follow this way => https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/242967/51810

Comment: thanks but when arriving to composer update i got the same error

Comment: Do a **composer clearcache** . Check the credentials in both 1. **root** cat auth.json 2. **Outside root** cat ~/.composer/auth.json , check if you have the key enabled .